# How do we call a virtual method from another method in the base class even when the current instance is of a derived-class?

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class, virtual-functions

How do we call a virtual method from another method in the base class even when the current instance is of a derived-class?

I know we can call **Method2** in the **Base** class from a method in the **Derived** class by using **base.Method2()** but what I want to do is calling it from the other virtual method in the **Base** class. Is it possible?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      Base b = new Derived(  );
      b.Method1(  );
    }
  }


  public class Base
  {
    public virtual void Method1()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Method1 in Base class.");
      this.Method2( );   // I want this line to always call Method2 in Base class, even if the current instance is a Derived object.
      // I want 'this' here to always refer to the Base class. Is it possible?
    }

    public virtual void Method2()
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "Method2 in Base class." );
    }
  }

  public class Derived : Base
  {
    public override void Method1()
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "Method1 in Derived class." );
      base.Method1();
    }

    public override void Method2()
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "Method2 in Derived class." );
    }
  }

}
```

With the above codes, it will output:

```
Method1 in Derived class.
Method1 in Base class.
Method2 in Derived class.
```

while what I would expect is:

```
Method1 in Derived class.
Method1 in Base class.
Method2 in Base class.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you cannot do that, the purpose of virtual methods is that derived classes can override the implementation and that the implementation is used even when called from base classes.

If that causes problems then the code you need to run should not be in a virtual method.

Comment: I want a method that can be overriden, yet it can be called directly in the base class when needed. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: @newgps You will need to pull the code out into another method then as per Henrik's solution and my advice.

Answer (score 8):

Obvious solution:

```
    public virtual void Method1()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Method1 in Base class.");
      this.Method2Private( );
    }

    private void Method2Private()
    {
      Console.WriteLine( "Method2 in Base class." );
    }

    public virtual void Method2()
    {
      Method2Private();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Henrik. Your solution does work, but I am wondering if we can do it without having to add another method.