# How to make base class call its virtual function?

Tags: c#

For example in the following program I want `entrypoint()` in `A` to be able to call  `doThis` in `A`, but it calls `doThis` in B since that's the instance type. How can I achieve what I want?

```
void Main()
{
    A a = new B();
    a.entrypoint();
}

public class A
{
    public void entrypoint()
    {
        this.doThis(); //doesn't call A::doThis()
    }

    public virtual void doThis()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("From A");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void doThis()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("From B");
    }
}
```

edit: [How can I call the 'base implementation' of an overridden virtual method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334254/how-can-i-call-the-base-implementation-of-an-overridden-virtual-method?rq=1) is similar but I'm calling the base implementation from base class not main.

edit: similar to [How do we call a virtual method from another method in the base class even when the current instance is of a derived-class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922092/how-do-we-call-a-virtual-method-from-another-method-in-the-base-class-even-when?rq=1)

Comment: If you override the virtual method in derived class,only the overridden method will be called.If you don't override it the base class method will be invoked

Comment: If you want to call a function in base, then it can't be virtual.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way would arguably be to not call a virtual method if you need it to not be overridden. I'd propose making a private method to do what you want.

Comment: Making it private actually worked for me even though I thought my whole design was dependent on the virtual function.

Comment: I cannot see why it cannot be useful to call a base's version on occasion, and the derived object's implementation as default in all other cases. For example it's no problem in C++ where you just qualify with the base classe's name (even in the base classe's implementation itself), i.e. instead of `this.doThis()` `A::doThis()`

Comment: @PeterSchneider It's not that it could never be useful, but it definitely has a "code smell" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). It's just screaming out that there's a design flaw.

Comment: @itsme86 Yeah, one should sure know what one's doing, like so often. As an aside, one can utilize managed C++ to do the required job in .net: http://couldbedone.blogspot.de/2007/08/calling-virtual-method-of-class-base-to.html, or reflection, naturally.